# How to sort query result by argument of list order?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

The query below return all items with id from `:ids` list. But table and input list have different order. Is there way to add something like pseudocode `ORDER BY :ids`?

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM item_table WHERE type = :type AND itemId IN (:ids)")
fun getPagingSource(type: EntityType, ids: List<String>): PagingSource<Int, ItemEntity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is instead of passing the ids as a List to be checked with the operator `IN`, to pass them as a comma separated string, something like `'36,3,14'` and use the operator `LIKE` in the `WHERE` clause to filter the rows.

Then, in the `ORDER BY` clause use the string function `INSTR()` to sort the rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM item_table 
WHERE type = :type
  AND ',' || :ids || ',' LIKE '%,' || itemId || ',%'
ORDER BY INSTR(',' || :ids || ',', ',' || itemId || ',');
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/25YMFghd).